# How to push the list items from the api to the initial default state in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have question and problem regarding on pushing the api list data to the initial default state that I manually created inside the Slice. I use react js and state management redux toolkit. I hope guys it cleared to you.

**Initial State:**

```
initialDefaultReceiveChecks:{
        data:[
            {
                'customer_payor': null,
                'bank': null,
                'bank_branch': null,
                'check_no': null,
                'check_date': null,
                'amount': null,
                'remarks': null,
            },
            {
                'customer_payor': null,
                'bank': null,
                'bank_branch': null,
                'check_no': null,
                'check_date': null,
                'amount': null,
                'remarks': null,
            },
            {
                'customer_payor': null,
                'bank': null,
                'bank_branch': null,
                'check_no': null,
                'check_date': null,
                'amount': null,
                'remarks': null,
            },
            {
                'customer_payor': null,
                'bank': null,
                'bank_branch': null,
                'check_no': null,
                'check_date': null,
                'amount': null,
                'remarks': null,
            },
            {
                'customer_payor': null,
                'bank': null,
                'bank_branch': null,
                'check_no': null,
                'check_date': null,
                'amount': null,
                'remarks': null,
            }
        ]
    }
```

**List Banks:** This list banks already dispatch.

[image: List Banks]

**Problem:** As you can see I have initial state of initialDefaultReceiveChecks. Inside of the data there is bank of null so my question how can i push my list banks that object?.

**Output will be:**

```
initialDefaultReceiveChecks: {
  data: [
    {
      'customer_payor': null,
      'bank': list of banks to be here
      'bank_branch': null,
      'check_no': null,
      'check_date': null,
      'amount': null,
      'remarks': null,
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, something other than dispatching an action with the new `bank` data as a payload?

Comment: You need to have some unique id for each initial and incoming entry to match them with each other. Is it possible? And anyways... can I ask why do you need a list of empty items as inital state?

Comment: what i mean on my question. yes I have 5 initial state manually created , but if the useEffect detect there is a value inside the list bank. then this initial state bank will replace all the list banks have.

Comment: @gazdagergo they want to have 5 default table rows thats why i created 5 data in default.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let initialObj =  {...this.state.initialDefaultReceiveChecks};
let arr = initialObj.data.map(ele=>ele.bank =list_banks.data;
initialObj.data= arr ; 
{...state,
initialDefaultReceiveChecks:initialObj}
```